# Low res texture in UV map with repetitive polygons

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a really simple object with less than 20 polygons, that is used on a platform for my game. I was able to model and unwrapped it, but I want to resize all the side polygons so they are 32px high, and stack them together (as they are all the same).

Also, I wanted to know if it was possible to set the resolution of the UV-map viewport (where the 2D texture is displayed) so it has a resolution according to my target texture, and the polygons faces are aligned.

Here is the picture of what I have done so far: [image]

Comment: What do you mean by setting the resolution of the viewport? It already displays the images at the size of the scale of the UVMaps.

Comment: @CharlesL But the 'resolution' of the polygons on the UV viewport is waaay higher than the resolution of my texture.

Comment: Your screen shot shows that you have chosen a UV Grid with a resolution of 64 x 64, giving you a set of four squares with red and yellow plus signs in them. Is this the 'resolution' you are referring to? If so, it would be better if you accepted the default resolution of 1024 x 1024, or, if you have a texture, then make its resolution 1024 x 1024.

Comment: @SteveW No, I mean the resolution of the polygons (the top and bottom part, and the sides). I want to align them to my small texture, pixel by pixel. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Do you mean that the polygon 'faces' are different sizes relative to each other in the UV/Image Editor, and so will have different resolutions where they meet on the object?

Comment: @SteveW Exactly

Comment: I think you will find that the relative sizes will match up correctly as they are, - but I might attempt to answer your question anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UV Editor (as shown in your picture), select one of the 'sides' (position the mouse cursor over one and hit <kbd>L</kbd>) then hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> - this will make it fill the image vertically at 64px high. Now scale it by half <kbd>S</kbd> (.5). Do the same with all the other 'sides' (not the top or bottom), they should now sit neatly one on top of the other, and be 32px high. 
Position the 2D Cursor on one of the vertices at the bottom of the 'sides' (select a vertex and hit <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> > Cursor to Selected),

[image]

and then set the pivot to 2D Cursor.

[image]

Now grab <kbd>G</kbd> the 'bottom' and position one of it's vertices on the 2D Cursor and then scale (S) until the next vertex lines up as shown.

[image]

Do the same with the 'top'. Now all resolutions should be the same and the sides will be 32px high. I hope this solves the problem.